# Активация свернутого приложение с двумя формами

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день, имееться приложение. Для простоты с двумя формами. `mainForm` и `customerCardForm`. `customerCardForm` вызываеться таким образом.

```
customerCardForm sc = new customerCardForm();
sc.companyID = clickedCell.Value.ToString();
sc.Show();
```

Когда я задаю значение `true` для параметра `TopMost` форма `customerCardForm`, то его не возможно даже сварачиват. Это форма сверх всех элементов, даже если открыт браузер. Задаю значение `false` для параметра  `TopMost` форма `customerCardForm`, и далее открываю иные программы, после активации приложение с панели задачь, рисуеться форма `mainForm`, несмотря на то что, форма `customerCardForm` было вызвано до этого.

Как управлять данным процессом, чтобы если дочерная форма запушена, то после перехода в программу, она была сверху своего родителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `Show` имеет перегрузку, которая принимает ссылку на окно-владельца. Передавайте указатель на родительскую форму:

```
sc.Show(this);
```

В результате дочернее окно будет всегда поверх родительского.